# Intelligent spaceship vs imprisoned monster - What is the name of the story?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I am trying to find the name of a scifi story I read probably 40 years ago.

I don't remember all the elements, but there is a spaceship that itself communicates with a young man on Earth (or other planet). The ship is almost the main character. I believe the ship chose the man for some reason. The ship may take the man to other planets, and at various points in the story protects the man while on a planet with a personal shield.

What I remember is just a very, very sophisticated spaceship with a chosen human partner from a planet, with the mission of solving the problem of an imprisoned beast.

There is a very dangerous creature imprisoned in a very distant system by a possibly extinct civilization which made the spaceship. The prison may be at the center of the galaxy. There may be three suns in the prison system.

I don't remember the plot but I remember I really liked the story and would like to read it again. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Novel or short story?

Comment: Was it in English or another language? Was it translated?

Comment: Could it be related to "The Ship Who Sang" or any other of the stories of intelligent spaceships by Anne McCaffrey? These stories were written in the 60s.

Comment: @user14111: I believe it was a novel, or at least a lengthy short story   :-)

Comment: Was it set it the far future, near future, or present day?

Comment: @Xantec: I read it in English; don't know if it was a translation.

Comment: @Andres F.: I will use Amazon to check her books ... thanks.

Comment: @user14111: I believe it was far future ...

Comment: @Andres F.: I don't believe Anne McCaffrey was the author. There were no dragons, families, romance, etc. Just a spaceship with a chosen human partner, with the mission of solving the problem of the imprisoned beast.

Comment: Yeah, probably it wasn't her. Bear in mind, however, that Anne's "intelligent ship" stories are unrelated to her "Dragonriders of Pern" stories -- which I believe she's more well-known for -- and there are no dragons in them, as far as I know :)

Comment: This reminds me somehow of a short story by Bob Shaw. I think it was in an anthology by him set in a spaceship. Memory failure at this point - sorry

Comment: Further to my earlier Bob Shaw comment. The Gray Man is in an anthology of his called Ship of Strangers. The Ship captain is a powerful A.I. and it's on a very long exploration voyage with different planet landings making up the stories. In the Gray Man the ship brain comes up against the predatory psychic creature trapped on a planet. There are various methods tried by the scared crew as the thing is infiltrating but then the Gray Man makes some kind of error against the AI